# When to add a field to an asset?

Tags: assets, field, entry-type

I've added a field to an asset which in my case is a fallback image for a video asset.

When uploading a video the field for the fallback image isn't visible so the chances of forgetting to set one is bigger.

To set the fallback image I need to edit my video asset and set the fallback image in there.

In my case I'd rather set the fallback image in the entrytype so it won't get forgotten.

When does it make sense to add the field directly to the asset instead of defining a field in a entrytype?

Fieldlayout entrytype version:

- Video (asset)
- Video Thumbnail (asset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense, when it's a task that should only be done **once** and is directly related to the asset.

A good example I have of an Asset custom field is a field allowing the content-administrator to define where an images focal point is positioned e.g. top left, bottom right, top right, etc.

I'm able to make use of the field EVERY time I display the image asset, but only need to deal with the custom field, once.

---

Part deux (in answer to your comment):

Yes, in my experience, although you can also double click an asset from the new/edit entry screen and see it's custom fields e.g. "Focal point position". See image below...

[image]

Comment: That's what i was expecting. 

Is editing an asset to set said field the only way to set it?

Comment: As far as I know, yes - see my edit...