# Add fields to image popup

Tags: assets, field, redactor, richtext

Is it possible to add additional fields to the image popup in redactor? In addition to Title, Caption and Link.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way without hacking Redactor or adding a custom Redactor plugin that mimics/extends the existing Image/Link button functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If the content of the additional field(s) is directly related to the image itself, then adding custom fields to the Asset-Source might be a solution for you.

Click **Settings** > **Assets** > (click the relevant Asset Source Title)

- Add any custom fields as needed.

The beauty of this approach is that the additional data is tied to the asset and so once entered, can be made use of as needed.

[Here's a good example...](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/14410/when-to-add-a-field-to-an-asset/14414#14414)

Comment: This doesn't work within a Rich Text field though.